# angularjs console.log the class name of element which has class applied via ternary operator

Tags: angularjs, class, console.log, ternary

I have an element that has class applied via ternary operation

Eg:

```
<div id="expand" ng-show="!model.displayItem" ng-click="toggleDisplay()" class="{model.displayItem?'Expand':'Collapse'}" focus-index="{model.displayItem?'101':'102'}">
```

I want to print the value of the class that gets finally applied in toggleDisplay()

```
function toggleDisplay()
{
 console.log("Class applied : " +  $("#expand").attr('class'));

}
```

When I print this the result is

```
o/p:-
Class applied : {model.displayItem?'Expand':'Collapse'}
```

How can I get only the class name that is currently applied?

Similarly I want to print the focus-index too.

Comment: when you are applying `console.log` inside controller or outside angular??

Comment: use `ng-class` for that syntax

Comment: What I really want to do is print the value that gets finally applied i.e. the class name and focus index

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-class="model.displayItem?'Expand':'Collapse'"`
instead of `class="{model.displayItem?'Expand':'Collapse'}"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the templated variables incorrect you need {{expression}} rather than {expression}

The following works for me:

```
<div class="{{model.displayItem?'Expand':'Collapse'}}">
<h1>hello</h1>
</div>
```

Aidan

Answer (score 0):

Before angular loads your class will literally be `{model.displayItem?'Expand':'Collapse'}`.

So use `ng-class="model.displayItem?'Expand':'Collapse'"` as it waits for angular to run its first digest.